# Negotiating an overseas salary

Tags: salary

I've been offered a local hire job in Hong Kong, however, the job position requires an international employee.

I love the jobscope and growth opportunities tagged to the career, however, I am not able to survive on the salary. I understand that the salary is slightly below the median household income in Hong Kong. The pay offered to me is the same as what other jobs in my country are offering. The rent in Hong Kong as well as daily living expenses will take a huge chunk out of my salary, leaving me without much savings (around $540 USD) each month.

How do I negotiate and seek a higher salary when I'll be leaving my family behind and yet still get a pay that is not competitive at all?

The only reason why I'm rejecting is the salary.

About myself: I am a graduate with a first class honours with 2 years of relevant work experience.

Comment: The his should be the same as negotiating salary for any other job. "I know cost of living is different there, but I need to keep on track for my long-term savings plan so I would need ... above cost of living. Can you raise that to ...?"

Comment: @keshlam You should make your comment an answer.  ( the answer IMHO )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the fact you have to leave your family behind makes it hard to move, it does not change the main reason of your refusal :  *The only reason why I'm rejecting is the salary.*

Clarify what is the salary you expect, and be prepared to justify why you expect and deserve it. **You have to establish the salary threshold for taking the job.** Under this number, reject the job. Above this number, take the job.

You should call, or send an email stating very clearly that the proposed salary is below your expectations, and that you cannot afford to move to Hong Kong without a salary of [XXX]. Be explicit that you *cannot* live with less, and this figure is your absolute minimum.